# OTLPExporterError: Not Found when sending metrics using @opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node/register

Tags: javascript, express, metrics, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am running a NodeJS TypeScript API server and it requires an auto instrumentation using OpenTelemetry with the following command when starting the app:

```
node --require @opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node/register index.js
```

package.json:

```
"@opentelemetry/api": "^1.7.0",
"@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node": "^0.41.0",
```

Environment Variables on NodeJS server:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://<otel-collector>:4318/
```

OTEL Collector configurations in `otel-collector-config.yaml`:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug]
```

All traces from the server can be sent to OTEL Collector normally. However, there are no metrics sending to OTEL Collector at all. After trying to remove `traces` from `otel-collector-config.yaml`, the following error popped up instead:

```
{"stack":"OTLPExporterError: Not Found\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/otlp-exporter-base/build/src/platform/node/util.js:103:39)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:55\n    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (async_hooks.js:303:14)\n    at AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.with (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AsyncLocalStorageContextManager.js:33:40)\n    at IncomingMessage.contextWrapper (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@opentelemetry/context-async-hooks/build/src/AbstractAsyncHooksContextManager.js:50:32)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)\n    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1333:12)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)","message":"Not Found","name":"OTLPExporterError","data":"404 page not found\n","code":"404"}
```

I tried to specify the endpoint of OTLP metrics as `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT=http://<otel-collector>:4318/v1/metrics` or even changed to Prometheus `/otlp/v1/metrics` instead of OTEL collector but it returned the same error.

I expected that metrics should be sent to OTEL collector normally.

Please advise if I missed anything.

Comment: API and auto-instrumentations-node do not include the SDK. Can you provide the full list of OpenTelemetry packages installed, and the code used to set up your opentelemtry SDK? I think you most likely don't have the metrics SDK setup or do not have the exporter installed.

Comment: Hi @DannyDyla, I followed the approach from GrowthBook https://github.com/growthbook/growthbook/blob/main/packages/back-end/package.json by adding only api and auto-instrumentations-node as dependencies. Unfortunately, when I run GrowthBook on my local computer, I also got the same issue.